# create multi-thread

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, compiler-errors

I use Multi-thread method in vs2008 ,use c++ language.  when I use `_beginthreadex` function， I got the follow error:

```
error C2664: '_beginthreadex' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'unsigned int
(__stdcall *)(void *)' to 'unsigned int (__stdcall *)(void *)'
```

ps: I use the template on the threadFunc like this:

`template<class T>
unsigned int  WINAPI closingReconstruction_ThreadFunc(void* pvPara)
{...}`

,and then i creat the thread

```
_beginthreadex(NULL,0,closingReconstruction_ThreadFunc<T>,(PVOID)(tPara+i),0,NULL)
```

so i get this error , of course , if I remove the template ,it can be work,but i need to use template, are there any  methods to solve this.

Comment: could you post the code that generates the problem pls?

Comment: That is a highly unusual error message. Do you have some example code that triggers this?

Comment: The underscore before `_beginthreadex` implies that its something internal.

Comment: @Dani: True in general, but IIRC, in MSVC, that's indeed the standard function to call to spawn a thread.

Comment: @Dani:  A lot of platform-specific CRT functions have a leading underscore.  Names beginning with a leading underscore are reserved for the implementation to use.

Comment: @Chris: If you're gonna "fix the formatting", you could at least break the lines up so the error is actually visible without scrolling all the way over... :P  Course, this not actually being code, shouldn't be formatted as code anyway IMO. It was perfectly readable before you messed with it...

Comment: @cHao: Actually, I wasn't actually kvetching at your edit, but the one two revisions before. Feel free to do the non-code version if you really, really object. I do want to keep the backticks for `_beginthreadex` and `threadFunc` in the prose paragraphs, though.

Comment: @Chris: My main problem with it was the scrolling thing.  It's not horrible as code, long as the line's broken up.

Comment: @cHao: In that case, your edit is all good. :-)

Comment: Visual C++ is known to have problems with templates

Comment: @Samuel: It'd help if you included the declaration for your `threadFunc` (template stuff and all), and the code that calls `_beginthreadex`.  The error as it stands isn't enough to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Dani: VC6, yeah.  Things have gotten better since then, though...

Comment: Strictly speaking, `extern "C"` is a required part of the calling convention, but I don't think that's going to make a difference on Visual C++.

Comment: Does the following line compile: `unsigned ( __stdcall *start_address )( void * ) = &closingReconstruction_ThreadFunc<T>;` ?

Comment: @Ben Voigt: It doesn't- that's why the function prototype isn't decorated that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to mention the immediately preceding error message,

> error C2065: 'T' : undeclared identifier

Let me just state that looking at the first error message first, is generally a good idea.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: If this is indeed the problem, it's definitely facepalm-worthy.  It's definitely a good guess.